# How much memory should I allocate the virtual machine for Elasticsearch server

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to connect 15 devices (cisco routers/swtiches, and fortigate firewall) to my Elasticsearch. I have read the documentation and know the rules for allocating the heap memory but they don't provide the logic to choose how much memory my device or VM should have.

Answer (score 0):

this will depend on how much data each device generates, and then long you want to keep the data for

start with 8GB, with 4GB for heap, and then scale up as needed